# Rails nested model form error on updating children

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a `Person` model and a `Business` model both of which `have_many contacts, as:contactable`

I am not sure of the correct way to update a nested model, but what I have done is as follows:

my params hash is as follows:

```
{"person"=>
  {"name"=>"updated name",
   .......
   "contacts_attributes"=>
    {"0"=>{"contact_type"=>"web", "contact_sub_type"=>"main", "address"=>"http:www.example.com/changed", "id"=>"2"},
     "1"=>{"contact_type"=>"twitter", "contact_sub_type"=>"main", "address"=>"changedtwerson", "id"=>"4"},
"2"=> {contact_type: "facebook", contact_sub_type: "main" , id: "3" },
"3"=> {contact_type: "email", contact_sub_type: "main",id: "1" }
}},
     "submit"=>"save",
     "id"=>"1",
     "controller"=>"persons",
     "action"=>"update"}
```

Within the model I already have 3 `person.contacts` for `Contact.contact_type` "web", "facebook" and "twitter" with `contact_sub_type` corresponding to the inputs above.

Within the Contact model I have `validates_uniqueness_of :contact_type, scope: [:contact_sub_type, :contactable_id ]`

Because if address is blank, I do not want to load the contact to the Person/Business object I have included in the method to set strong params code to destroy_all records which do not have an address:

```
def person_params
    contact_list = params[:person][:contacts_attributes].delete_if { |key, value| value[:address].blank? } if params[:person].present? && params[:person][:contacts_attributes].present?
    cl_ary = []
    contact_list.values.each { |v| cl_ary << v[:id] }
    @person.contacts.where.not(id: cl_ary).destroy_all if @person && @person.contacts

    params.require(:person).permit(:name, ......
                    contacts_attributes: [:id, :address, :contact_type, :contact_sub_type]) unless params[:person].nil?
end
```

When I call 
@person = Person.find(id: params[:id])
@person.update person_params

I get a value false returned and the @person is invalid as the `:contact_type=>["has already been taken"]`

after update `@person.contacts` gives me the following (which to me should pass the unique validation)

```
[#<Contact id: 4, contact_type: "twitter", contact_sub_type: "main", address: "changedtwerson", contactable_id: 1, contactable_type: "Person", created_at: "2014-12-12 10:09:15", updated_at: "2014-12-12 10:09:24">, #<Contact id: 2, contact_type: "web", contact_sub_type: "main", address: "http:www.example.com/changed", contactable_id: 1, contactable_type: "Person", created_at: "2014-12-12 10:09:15", updated_at: "2014-12-12 10:09:24">]
```

I therefore have 2 questions:

1. Do I have a valid approach here, have I missed anything and is there a better way?
2. How can I look further into the validation and find out why the validation is failing when it looks OK visually?

Answer (score 1):

Answer for question 1: this is not a valid approach.

Refactor `Person` class by adding:

`accepts_nested_attributes_for :contacts, :allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => proc {|attrs| attrs[:address].blank?}`

and from `person_params` method remove:

`contact_list = params[:person][:contacts_attributes].delete_if { |key, value| value[:address].blank? } if params[:person].present? && params[:person][:contacts_attributes].present?
    cl_ary = []
    contact_list.values.each { |v| cl_ary << v[:id] }
    @person.contacts.where.not(id: cl_ary).destroy_all if @person && @person.contacts`

Also change validator to:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :contact_type, scope: [:contact_sub_type, :contactable_id, :contactable_type]
```

to prevent Person/Business race conditions.

Refactor `update` action to:

```
@person = Person.find(id: params[:id])
@person.attributes = person_params 
@person.contacts.select {|x| x.address.blank?}.each(&:mark_for_destruction)
@person.save
```

Comment: Thanks, you just beat me to that change. However it only allows the removal  contacts from the params hash which have a blank address. The person_params returns a hash with just contacts with an address. However if the existing person has 4 contacts and 1 is provided in the hash (after rejection), 3 should be removed from the db and that is what the second part (destroy_all) is trying to do. By just rejecting any blanks addresses the 1 is updated, but the other 3 remain unchanged, instead of being deleted.

Comment: In my oppinion invalid data should not be saved into DB. Model validation  should prevent from such scenario. If you already have corrupted data than remove it manually.

Comment: Absolutely agreed. All contacts in the database have an address, but when this is presented on the form the user can delete the address and this is then submitted as an invalid record (this is because I have hidden fields on the form categorising the field (id/contact_type/sub_type)... I'll update the question to reflect this. It is these empty records that the reject_if will remove, but if these are stored in the database update will not automatically delete them. hence the destroy_all action.

Comment: Code responsible for records removal eg. `destroy_all` should go to `update` action. If you want to remove records with blank addresses than remove all `:remove_if` in `accepts_nested_attributes_for` from your `Person` model and refactor `update` action to:
`@person = Person.find(id: params[:id])
@person.attributes = person_params
@person.contacts.select {|x| x.address.blank?}.each(&:mark_for_destruction)
@person.save`

Comment: Unfortunately this seems to be a backward step. I'm maybe not fully understanding. You are right, the "`destroy_all`" should be in `update`, not shared with `create`. I'm not sure what you mean by "remove all `:remove_if`?  The code in the comment above does mark for destruction those blank address contacts where they were not already set in the database, but if changed from populated to blank, they are just left. Finally it does not solve the underlying problem that the save fails because one of the contacts, in this case "web" is deemed to already exist, though I cannot understand why.

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo error. You should remove `:reject_if` code (not `:remove_if`) from `Person` class if you want to be able to process all passed attributes in the controller (even those with blank addresses). Can you provide all of your validation code because I don't understand when address can/cannot be provided? Also change validator to: `validates_uniqueness_of :contact_type, scope: [:contact_sub_type, :contactable_id, :contactable_type]` to prevent `Person`/`Business` race conditions.

Comment: Thanks do much @olhor that solves it. I'll also incorporate the `mark_for_destruction` rather than destroy_all, move it to the update method and make sure it picks up the right records already in the database. I also need to keep the :reject_if to filter out the invalid contacts. Then I think that I am done. Fundamentally though it seems to have been that validation all along. If you would like to update your answer, then I'll mark it. Thanks Again.